# Python-Bluetooth-App: BleakDeviceNotFoundError: Device with address 9C:FC:E8:73:87:EA was not found

Tags: python-3.x, bluetooth, dbus, bluez

Hi guys i would like to programming a python3 smartphone app which i can use to configure a gateway device over bluetooth.

with the following codes i implement the bluetooth connection itself.

This is the script i run on the gateway, which creates a bluetooth agent on it:

```
import logging

import dbus
import dbus.exceptions
import dbus.mainloop.glib
import dbus.service

import struct
import requests
import array
from enum import Enum

MainLoop = None
try:
    from gi.repository import GLib

    MainLoop = GLib.MainLoop
except ImportError:
    import gobject as GObject

    MainLoop = GObject.MainLoop

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
filelogHandler = logging.FileHandler("logs.log")
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
logHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
filelogHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(filelogHandler)
logger.addHandler(logHandler)


VivaldiBaseUrl = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"

mainloop = None

DBUS_OM_IFACE = "org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager"
DBUS_PROP_IFACE = "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties"

GATT_SERVICE_IFACE = "org.bluez.GattService1"
GATT_CHRC_IFACE = "org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1"
GATT_DESC_IFACE = "org.bluez.GattDescriptor1"

LE_ADVERTISING_MANAGER_IFACE = "org.bluez.LEAdvertisingManager1"
LE_ADVERTISEMENT_IFACE = "org.bluez.LEAdvertisement1"

BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME = "org.bluez"
GATT_MANAGER_IFACE = "org.bluez.GattManager1"

class InvalidArgsException(dbus.exceptions.DBusException):
    _dbus_error_name = "org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs"


class NotSupportedException(dbus.exceptions.DBusException):
    _dbus_error_name = "org.bluez.Error.NotSupported"

class NotPermittedException(dbus.exceptions.DBusException):
    _dbus_error_name = "org.bluez.Error.NotPermitted"


class InvalidValueLengthException(dbus.exceptions.DBusException):
    _dbus_error_name = "org.bluez.Error.InvalidValueLength"


class FailedException(dbus.exceptions.DBusException):
    _dbus_error_name = "org.bluez.Error.Failed"


def register_app_cb():
    logger.info("GATT application registered")


def register_app_error_cb(error):
    logger.critical("Failed to register application: " + str(error))
    mainloop.quit()

class Advertisement(dbus.service.Object):
    PATH_BASE = "/org/bluez/example/advertisement"

    def __init__(self, bus, index, advertising_type):
        self.path = self.PATH_BASE + str(index)
        self.bus = bus
        self.ad_type = advertising_type
        self.service_uuids = None
        self.manufacturer_data = None
        self.solicit_uuids = None
        self.service_data = None
        self.local_name = None
        self.include_tx_power = None
        self.data = None
        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, bus, self.path)

    def get_properties(self):
        properties = dict()
        properties["Type"] = self.ad_type
        if self.service_uuids is not None:
            properties["ServiceUUIDs"] = dbus.Array(self.service_uuids, signature="s")
        if self.solicit_uuids is not None:
            properties["SolicitUUIDs"] = dbus.Array(self.solicit_uuids, signature="s")
        if self.manufacturer_data is not None:
            properties["ManufacturerData"] = dbus.Dictionary(
                self.manufacturer_data, signature="qv"
            )
        if self.service_data is not None:
            properties["ServiceData"] = dbus.Dictionary(
                self.service_data, signature="sv"
            )
        if self.local_name is not None:
            properties["LocalName"] = dbus.String(self.local_name)
        if self.include_tx_power is not None:
            properties["IncludeTxPower"] = dbus.Boolean(self.include_tx_power)

        if self.data is not None:
            properties["Data"] = dbus.Dictionary(self.data, signature="yv")
        return {LE_ADVERTISEMENT_IFACE: properties}

    def get_path(self):
        return dbus.ObjectPath(self.path)

    def add_service_uuid(self, uuid):
        if not self.service_uuids:
            self.service_uuids = []
        self.service_uuids.append(uuid)

    def add_solicit_uuid(self, uuid):
        if not self.solicit_uuids:
            self.solicit_uuids = []
        self.solicit_uuids.append(uuid)

    def add_manufacturer_data(self, manuf_code, data):
        if not self.manufacturer_data:
            self.manufacturer_data = dbus.Dictionary({}, signature="qv")
        self.manufacturer_data[manuf_code] = dbus.Array(data, signature="y")

    def add_service_data(self, uuid, data):
        if not self.service_data:
            self.service_data = dbus.Dictionary({}, signature="sv")
        self.service_data[uuid] = dbus.Array(data, signature="y")

    def add_local_name(self, name):
        if not self.local_name:
            self.local_name = ""
        self.local_name = dbus.String(name)

    def add_data(self, ad_type, data):
        if not self.data:
            self.data = dbus.Dictionary({}, signature="yv")
        self.data[ad_type] = dbus.Array(data, signature="y")

    @dbus.service.method(DBUS_PROP_IFACE, in_signature="s", out_signature="a{sv}")
    def GetAll(self, interface):
        logger.info("GetAll")
        if interface != LE_ADVERTISEMENT_IFACE:
            raise InvalidArgsException()
        logger.info("returning props")
        return self.get_properties()[LE_ADVERTISEMENT_IFACE]

    @dbus.service.method(LE_ADVERTISEMENT_IFACE, in_signature="", out_signature="")
    def Release(self):
        logger.info("%s: Released!" % self.path)


class VivaldiAdvertisement(Advertisement):
    def __init__(self, bus, index):
        Advertisement.__init__(self, bus, index, "peripheral")
        self.add_manufacturer_data(
            0xFFFF, [0x70, 0x74],
        )
        self.add_service_uuid("e2d36f99-8909-4136-9a49-d825508b297b")

        self.add_local_name(deviceNameInput)
        self.include_tx_power = True

def find_adapter(bus):
    """
    Return the first object that the bluez service has that has a GattManager1 interface
    """
    remote_om = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object(BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME, "/"), DBUS_OM_IFACE)
    objects = remote_om.GetManagedObjects()

    for o, props in objects.items():
        if GATT_MANAGER_IFACE in props.keys():
            return o

    return None

class Application(dbus.service.Object):
    """
    org.bluez.GattApplication1 interface implementation
    """

    def __init__(self, bus):
        self.path = "/"
        self.services = []
        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, bus, self.path)

        

    def get_path(self):
        return dbus.ObjectPath(self.path)

    def add_service(self, service):
        self.services.append(service)

    @dbus.service.method(DBUS_OM_IFACE, out_signature="a{oa{sa{sv}}}")
    def GetManagedObjects(self):
        response = {}
        logger.info("GetManagedObjects")

        for service in self.services:
            response[service.get_path()] = service.get_properties()
            chrcs = service.get_characteristics()
            for chrc in chrcs:
                response[chrc.get_path()] = chrc.get_properties()
                descs = chrc.get_descriptors()
                for desc in descs:
                    response[desc.get_path()] = desc.get_properties()

        return response


class Service(dbus.service.Object):
    """
    org.bluez.GattService1 interface implementation
    """

    PATH_BASE = "/org/bluez/example/service"

    def __init__(self, bus, index, uuid, primary):
        self.path = self.PATH_BASE + str(index)
        self.bus = bus
        self.uuid = uuid
        self.primary = primary
        self.characteristics = []
        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, bus, self.path)

    def get_properties(self):
        return {
            GATT_SERVICE_IFACE: {
                "UUID": self.uuid,
                "Primary": self.primary,
                "Characteristics": dbus.Array(
                    self.get_characteristic_paths(), signature="o"
                ),
            }
        }

    def get_path(self):
        return dbus.ObjectPath(self.path)

    def add_characteristic(self, characteristic):
        self.characteristics.append(characteristic)

    def get_characteristic_paths(self):
        result = []
        for chrc in self.characteristics:
            result.append(chrc.get_path())
        return result

    def get_characteristics(self):
        return self.characteristics

    @dbus.service.method(DBUS_PROP_IFACE, in_signature="s", out_signature="a{sv}")
    def GetAll(self, interface):
        if interface != GATT_SERVICE_IFACE:
            raise InvalidArgsException()

        return self.get_properties()[GATT_SERVICE_IFACE]


class Characteristic(dbus.service.Object):
    """
    org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1 interface implementation
    """

    def __init__(self, bus, index, uuid, flags, service):
        self.path = service.path + "/char" + str(index)
        self.bus = bus
        self.uuid = uuid
        self.service = service
        self.flags = flags
        self.descriptors = []
        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, bus, self.path)

    def get_properties(self):
        return {
            GATT_CHRC_IFACE: {
                "Service": self.service.get_path(),
                "UUID": self.uuid,
                "Flags": self.flags,
                "Descriptors": dbus.Array(self.get_descriptor_paths(), signature="o"),
            }
        }

    def get_path(self):
        return dbus.ObjectPath(self.path)

    def add_descriptor(self, descriptor):
        self.descriptors.append(descriptor)

    def get_descriptor_paths(self):
        result = []
        for desc in self.descriptors:
            result.append(desc.get_path())
        return result

    def get_descriptors(self):
        return self.descriptors

    @dbus.service.method(DBUS_PROP_IFACE, in_signature="s", out_signature="a{sv}")
    def GetAll(self, interface):
        if interface != GATT_CHRC_IFACE:
            raise InvalidArgsException()

        return self.get_properties()[GATT_CHRC_IFACE]

    @dbus.service.method(GATT_CHRC_IFACE, in_signature="a{sv}", out_signature="ay")
    def ReadValue(self, options):
        logger.info("Default ReadValue called, returning error")
        raise NotSupportedException()

    @dbus.service.method(GATT_CHRC_IFACE, in_signature="aya{sv}")
    def WriteValue(self, value, options):
        logger.info("Default WriteValue called, returning error")
        raise NotSupportedException()

    @dbus.service.method(GATT_CHRC_IFACE)
    def StartNotify(self):
        logger.info("Default StartNotify called, returning error")
        raise NotSupportedException()

    @dbus.service.method(GATT_CHRC_IFACE)
    def StopNotify(self):
        logger.info("Default StopNotify called, returning error")
        raise NotSupportedException()

    @dbus.service.signal(DBUS_PROP_IFACE, signature="sa{sv}as")
    def PropertiesChanged(self, interface, changed, invalidated):
        pass



class Descriptor(dbus.service.Object):
    """
    org.bluez.GattDescriptor1 interface implementation
    """

    def __init__(self, bus, index, uuid, flags, characteristic):
        self.path = characteristic.path + "/desc" + str(index)
        self.bus = bus
        self.uuid = uuid
        self.flags = flags
        self.chrc = characteristic
        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, bus, self.path)

    def get_properties(self):
        return {
            GATT_DESC_IFACE: {
                "Characteristic": self.chrc.get_path(),
                "UUID": self.uuid,
                "Flags": self.flags,
            }
        }

    def get_path(self):
        return dbus.ObjectPath(self.path)

    @dbus.service.method(DBUS_PROP_IFACE, in_signature="s", out_signature="a{sv}")
    def GetAll(self, interface):
        if interface != GATT_DESC_IFACE:
            raise InvalidArgsException()

        return self.get_properties()[GATT_DESC_IFACE]

    @dbus.service.method(GATT_DESC_IFACE, in_signature="a{sv}", out_signature="ay")
    def ReadValue(self, options):
        logger.info("Default ReadValue called, returning error")
        raise NotSupportedException()

    @dbus.service.method(GATT_DESC_IFACE, in_signature="aya{sv}")
    def WriteValue(self, value, options):
        logger.info("Default WriteValue called, returning error")
        raise NotSupportedException()

AGENT_INTERFACE = "org.bluez.Agent1"
AGENT_PATH = "/com/punchthrough/agent"

def ask(prompt):
    try:
        return raw_input(prompt)
    except NameError:
        return input(prompt)

def set_trusted(path):
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    props = dbus.Interface(
        bus.get_object("org.bluez", path), "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties"
    )
    props.Set("org.bluez.Device1", "Trusted", True)


def dev_connect(path):
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    dev = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.bluez", path), "org.bluez.Device1")
    dev.Connect()


class Rejected(dbus.DBusException):
    _dbus_error_name = "org.bluez.Error.Rejected"


class Agent(dbus.service.Object):
    exit_on_release = True

    def set_exit_on_release(self, exit_on_release):
        self.exit_on_release = exit_on_release

    @dbus.service.method(AGENT_INTERFACE, in_signature="", out_signature="")
    def Release(self):
        logger.info("Release")
        if self.exit_on_release:
            mainloop.quit()

    @dbus.service.method(AGENT_INTERFACE, in_signature="os", out_signature="")
    def AuthorizeService(self, device, uuid):
        logger.info("AuthorizeService (%s, %s)" % (device, uuid))
        authorize = ask("Authorize connection (yes/no): ")
        if authorize == "yes":
            return
        raise Rejected("Connection rejected by user")

    @dbus.service.method(AGENT_INTERFACE, in_signature="o", out_signature="s")
    def RequestPinCode(self, device):
        logger.info("RequestPinCode (%s)" % (device))
        set_trusted(device)
        return ask("Enter PIN Code: ")

    @dbus.service.method(AGENT_INTERFACE, in_signature="o", out_signature="u")
    def RequestPasskey(self, device):
        logger.info("RequestPasskey (%s)" % (device))
        set_trusted(device)
        passkey = "yes"
        return dbus.UInt32(passkey)

    @dbus.service.method(AGENT_INTERFACE, in_signature="ouq", out_signature="")
    def DisplayPasskey(self, device, passkey, entered):
        logger.info("DisplayPasskey (%s, %06u entered %u)" % (device, passkey, entered))

    @dbus.service.method(AGENT_INTERFACE, in_signature="os", out_signature="")
    def DisplayPinCode(self, device, pincode):
        logger.info("DisplayPinCode (%s, %s)" % (device, pincode))

    @dbus.service.method(AGENT_INTERFACE, in_signature="ou", out_signature="")
    def RequestConfirmation(self, device, passkey):
        logger.info("RequestConfirmation (%s, %06d)" % (device, passkey))
        confirm = ask("Confirm passkey (yes/no): ")
        if confirm == "yes":
            set_trusted(device)
            return
        raise Rejected("Passkey doesn't match")

    @dbus.service.method(AGENT_INTERFACE, in_signature="o", out_signature="")
    def RequestAuthorization(self, device):
        logger.info("RequestAuthorization (%s)" % (device))
        auth = ask("Authorize? (yes/no): ")
        if auth == "yes":
            return
        raise Rejected("Pairing rejected")

    @dbus.service.method(AGENT_INTERFACE, in_signature="", out_signature="")
    def Cancel(self):
        logger.info("Cancel")

def register_ad_cb():
    logger.info("Advertisement registered")


def register_ad_error_cb(error):
    logger.critical("Failed to register advertisement: " + str(error))
    mainloop.quit()

def getData():
    testText = "these are the data from the gateway"
    return testText

class VivaldiS1Service(Service):
    """
    Dummy test service that provides characteristics and descriptors that
    exercise various API functionality.

    """

    ESPRESSO_SVC_UUID = "12634d89-d598-4874-8e86-7d042ee07ba7"

    def __init__(self, bus, index):
        Service.__init__(self, bus, index, self.ESPRESSO_SVC_UUID, True)
        self.add_characteristic(PowerControlCharacteristic(bus, 0, self))
        self.add_characteristic(BoilerControlCharacteristic(bus, 1, self))
        self.add_characteristic(AutoOffCharacteristic(bus, 2, self))

class PowerControlCharacteristic(Characteristic):
    uuid = "4116f8d2-9f66-4f58-a53d-fc7440e7c14e"
    description = b"Get/set machine power state {'ON', 'OFF', 'UNKNOWN'}"

    class State(Enum):
        on = "ON"
        off = "OFF"
        unknown = "UNKNOWN"

        @classmethod
        def has_value(cls, value):
            return value in cls._value2member_map_

    power_options = {"ON", "OFF", "UNKNOWN"}

    def __init__(self, bus, index, service):
        Characteristic.__init__(
            self, bus, index, self.uuid, ["encrypt-read", "encrypt-write"], service,
        )

        self.value = [0xFF]
        self.add_descriptor(CharacteristicUserDescriptionDescriptor(bus, 1, self))

    def ReadValue(self, options):
        logger.debug("power Read: " + repr(self.value))
        res = None
        try:
            res = requests.get(VivaldiBaseUrl + "/vivaldi")
            self.value = bytearray(res.json()["machine"], encoding="utf8")
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error getting status {e}")
            self.value = bytearray(self.State.unknown, encoding="utf8")

        return self.value

    def WriteValue(self, value, options):
        logger.debug("power Write: " + repr(value))
        cmd = bytes(value).decode("utf-8")
        if self.State.has_value(cmd):
            # write it to machine
            logger.info("writing {cmd} to machine")
            data = {"cmd": cmd.lower()}
            try:
                res = requests.post(VivaldiBaseUrl + "/vivaldi/cmds", json=data)
            except Exceptions as e:
                logger.error(f"Error updating machine state: {e}")
        else:
            logger.info(f"invalid state written {cmd}")
            raise NotPermittedException

        self.value = value


class BoilerControlCharacteristic(Characteristic):
    uuid = "322e774f-c909-49c4-bd7b-48a4003a967f"
    description = b"Get/set boiler power state can be `on` or `off`"

    def __init__(self, bus, index, service):
        Characteristic.__init__(
            self, bus, index, self.uuid, ["encrypt-read", "encrypt-write"], service,
        )

        self.value = []
        self.add_descriptor(CharacteristicUserDescriptionDescriptor(bus, 1, self))

    def ReadValue(self, options):
        logger.info("boiler read: " + repr(self.value))
        res = None
        try:
            res = requests.get(VivaldiBaseUrl + "/vivaldi")
            self.value = bytearray(res.json()["boiler"], encoding="utf8")
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error getting status {e}")

        return self.value

    def WriteValue(self, value, options):
        logger.info("boiler state Write: " + repr(value))
        cmd = bytes(value).decode("utf-8")

        # write it to machine
        logger.info("writing {cmd} to machine")
        data = {"cmd": "setboiler", "state": cmd.lower()}
        try:
            res = requests.post(VivaldiBaseUrl + "/vivaldi/cmds", json=data)
            logger.info(res)
        except Exceptions as e:
            logger.error(f"Error updating machine state: {e}")
            raise


class AutoOffCharacteristic(Characteristic):
    uuid = "9c7dbce8-de5f-4168-89dd-74f04f4e5842"
    description = b"Get/set autoff time in minutes"

    def __init__(self, bus, index, service):
        Characteristic.__init__(
            self, bus, index, self.uuid, ["secure-read", "secure-write"], service,
        )

        self.value = []
        self.add_descriptor(CharacteristicUserDescriptionDescriptor(bus, 1, self))

    def ReadValue(self, options):
        logger.info("auto off read: " + repr(self.value))
        res = None
        try:
            res = requests.get(VivaldiBaseUrl + "/vivaldi")
            self.value = bytearray(struct.pack("i", int(res.json()["autoOffMinutes"])))
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error getting status {e}")

        return self.value

    def WriteValue(self, value, options):
        logger.info("auto off write: " + repr(value))
        cmd = bytes(value)

        # write it to machine
        logger.info("writing {cmd} to machine")
        data = {"cmd": "autoOffMinutes", "time": struct.unpack("i", cmd)[0]}
        try:
            res = requests.post(VivaldiBaseUrl + "/vivaldi/cmds", json=data)
            logger.info(res)
        except Exceptions as e:
            logger.error(f"Error updating machine state: {e}")
            raise

class CharacteristicUserDescriptionDescriptor(Descriptor):
    """
    Writable CUD descriptor.
    """

    CUD_UUID = "2901"

    def __init__(
        self, bus, index, characteristic,
    ):

        self.value = array.array("B", characteristic.description)
        self.value = self.value.tolist()
        Descriptor.__init__(self, bus, index, self.CUD_UUID, ["read"], characteristic)

    def ReadValue(self, options):
        return self.value

    def WriteValue(self, value, options):
        if not self.writable:
            raise NotPermittedException()
        self.value = value




def main():

    global mainloop

    dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)

    # get the system bus
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    # get the ble controller
    adapter = find_adapter(bus)

    if not adapter:
        logger.critical("GattManager1 interface not found")
        return

    adapter_obj = bus.get_object(BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME, adapter)

    adapter_props = dbus.Interface(adapter_obj, "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties")

    # powered property on the controller to on
    adapter_props.Set("org.bluez.Adapter1", "Powered", dbus.Boolean(1))

    # Get manager objs
    service_manager = dbus.Interface(adapter_obj, GATT_MANAGER_IFACE)
    ad_manager = dbus.Interface(adapter_obj, LE_ADVERTISING_MANAGER_IFACE)

    advertisement = VivaldiAdvertisement(bus, 0)
    obj = bus.get_object(BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME, "/org/bluez")

    agent = Agent(bus, AGENT_PATH)

    app = Application(bus)
    app.add_service(VivaldiS1Service(bus, 2))

    mainloop = MainLoop()

    agent_manager = dbus.Interface(obj, "org.bluez.AgentManager1")
    agent_manager.RegisterAgent(AGENT_PATH, "NoInputNoOutput")

    ad_manager.RegisterAdvertisement(
        advertisement.get_path(),
        {},
        reply_handler=register_ad_cb,
        error_handler=register_ad_error_cb,
    )

    logger.info("Registering GATT application...")

    service_manager.RegisterApplication(
        app.get_path(),
        {},
        reply_handler=register_app_cb,
        error_handler=register_app_error_cb,
    )

    agent_manager.RequestDefaultAgent(AGENT_PATH)

    mainloop.run()
    # ad_manager.UnregisterAdvertisement(advertisement)
    # dbus.service.Object.remove_from_connection(advertisement)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    deviceNameInput=input("Enter the name under which you want to find the device:")
    main()
```

this is the Terminal on the gateway device:

```
Enter the name under which you want to find the device:gateway
2023-10-17 14:08:50,030 - __main__ - INFO - Registering GATT application...
2023-10-17 14:08:50,056 - __main__ - INFO - GetManagedObjects
2023-10-17 14:08:50,067 - __main__ - INFO - GetAll
2023-10-17 14:08:50,068 - __main__ - INFO - returning props
2023-10-17 14:08:50,084 - __main__ - INFO - GATT application registered
2023-10-17 14:08:50,090 - __main__ - INFO - Advertisement registered
```

And here is the Script on the PC which i want to connect to the gateway device:

```
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakScanner
from bleak import BleakClient
import os

class Device():
    def __init__(self, dName, dAddress):
        self.dName = dName
        self.dAddress = dAddress

    def getName(self):
        return self.dName
    
    def getAddress(self):
        return self.dAddress

async def findDevice():

    print("How would you like to search for the device?")
    questKindOfConnect = input("(name = name / add = address): ")

    if questKindOfConnect == "name":
        target_name = input("Enter the name of the device you are looking for:")
    elif questKindOfConnect == "add":
        target_address = input("Enter the address of the device you are looking for: ")

    print("searching for devices")
    near_devices = await BleakScanner.discover()
    found_devices = []

    for d in near_devices:
        newDevice = Device(d.name, d.address)

        if questKindOfConnect=="name":
            if target_name == d.name:
                found_devices.append(newDevice)

        if questKindOfConnect=="add":
            if target_address == d.address:
                found_devices.append(newDevice)

    return found_devices

class Main():
    async def run(self):
        listDevices = await findDevice()
        if listDevices:
            print("The device you are looking for has been found:")
            for y in listDevices:
                print("Name: "+y.getName() + ", Adresse:" + y.getAddress())
                await talkToDevice(y.getAddress())
        else:
            print("The device you are looking for has not been found!")

async def talkToDevice(adress):
    connectQuest=input("Do you want to connect to the device? (y/n):")
    if connectQuest == "y" or connectQuest == "Y" or connectQuest == "yes":
        async with BleakClient(adress) as client:
            await client.connect()

            text = await client.getData()
            print(text)

            await client.disconnect()

    elif connectQuest == "n" or connectQuest == "N" or connectQuest == "no":
        repeatQuest = input("Do you want to look for another device again? (y/n):")
        if repeatQuest == "y" or connectQuest == "Y" or connectQuest == "yes":
            main = Main()
            asyncio.run(main.run())

        if connectQuest == "n" or connectQuest == "N" or connectQuest == "no":
            print("Program is ending")
            os._exit(0)
        else:
            print("invalid entry")
            talkToDevice()

    else:
        print("invalid entry")
        talkToDevice()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Main()
    asyncio.run(main.run())
```

and this is the terminal on the PC with the error i want to solve:

```
sudo python3 answerApp.py 
[sudo] password for ssv: 
How would you like to search for the device?
(name = name / add = address): name
Enter the name of the device you are looking for:gateway
searching for devices
The device you are looking for has been found:
Name: gateway, Adresse:94:54:93:56:57:8C
Do you want to connect to the device? (y/n):y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ssv/Documents/Praxisphase/ProjektEmbededSystemConfigurationApp/BluetoothConnectionViaBluez/answerApp.py", line 85, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main.run())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/ssv/Documents/Praxisphase/ProjektEmbededSystemConfigurationApp/BluetoothConnectionViaBluez/answerApp.py", line 51, in run
    await talkToDevice(y.getAddress())
  File "/home/ssv/Documents/Praxisphase/ProjektEmbededSystemConfigurationApp/BluetoothConnectionViaBluez/answerApp.py", line 58, in talkToDevice
    async with BleakClient(adress) as client:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/bleak/__init__.py", line 565, in __aenter__
    await self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/bleak/__init__.py", line 605, in connect
    return await self._backend.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/bleak/backends/bluezdbus/client.py", line 244, in connect
    raise BleakDeviceNotFoundError(
bleak.exc.BleakDeviceNotFoundError: Device with address 94:54:93:56:57:8C was not found. It may have been removed from BlueZ when scanning stopped.
```

Does anyone have a idea how i can solve this problem?